# Finding duplicate records in a subset

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5.7, subquery

I have 3 tables:

- users
- orders
- order_items

I am trying to get a list of all orders by the same user that have the exact same `order_items.item_id` within a 24 hour period representing the user having placed a duplicate order for some reason.

I'm created [this db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eHr485b4sdzvCvi5FbGH4h/3) to represent this.

The results I am looking for are:

- orders 1, 2, 4 from user 1
- orders 7, 9 from user 2
- No orders from user 3

I've tried with this query but unfortunately it doesn't get the results and I am a bit lost on how I'd need to modify it to check for the right subset of orders having duplicate items. I'm assuming I might need to create a subquery on this but again have not figured out what will get the list of order IDs I need.

```
SELECT
    o.id 
FROM
    `users` u
    JOIN `orders` o ON u.id = o.user_id
    JOIN `order_items` oi ON oi.order_id = o.id 
WHERE
    `o`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2022-02-01 00:00:00' 
    AND '2022-02-02 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    oi.item_id, o.id 
HAVING
    count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: I suspect there is more than one column that determines an "item".  How would you determine that two `order_item` rows are the "same"?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` _might_ be a useful part of the query.

Comment: @RickJames because they have the same `item_id` value.